# "Invalid Host header" when running Angular/cli development server c9.io

Tags: angular, angular-cli, c9.io

Current command: `ng serve --host --public $IP:$PORT`

Results on my website:

> Invalid Host header

Comment: it's the same as above... the same result

Answer (score 211):

The `--disable-host-check` flag works fine if you need to run from Cloud9.

I use the following command:

```
ng serve --open --host $IP --port $PORT --disable-host-check
```

Comment: It will work but if you use `--disable-host-check` you will get a warning in the console. `WARNING: Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See` https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.

Comment: this option is not available anymore

Comment: I confirm the `--disable-host-check` flag is working in Angular version 14

Comment: @edi this is still relevant.

Comment: @Coffee-Tea it seems that this option is available again: see [ng serve](https://angular.io/cli/serve)

Answer (score 63):

In angular.json, add the following under **architect -> serve -> options**

```json
"disableHostCheck": true
```

Got the answer from this [Github Issue Page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11060#issuecomment-455535599)

Comment: Just want to point out that this resolves the issue for running locally on the machine. I'm not sure if it solves it for Cloud9 per the OP original question above.

Comment: This is the right an clean solution if you want to enable it on every `ng serve` (and probably you want to in development)

Comment: Is there a way to configure this for the development environment only?

Comment: @JellicleCat Set `"disableHostCheck": false` under **architect -> serve -> configurations -> production**

Answer (score 41):

You need to specify the host

```
ng serve --port 8080 --host 123.34.56.78
```

Answer (score 31):

This works for me :

```
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite PORT
```

for instance :

```
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 4200
```

Comment: Not the answer the OP needed, but thanks for adding it anyway. Works for ngrok tunneling without changing project settings.

Comment: I am building a Shopify app, I have to run `yarn start frontend --public-host=abc-xyz.ngrok.io` , with this answer, i can just `yarn start frontend` . I think the issue should be fixed with `disableHostCheck`.

Answer (score 19):

See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6070#issuecomment-298208974)

> Edit the following line in
>   `node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js` (line 425), change to:
>
> ```
> return true;
> ```
>
> I am using cloud9 IDE then run: `ng serve --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0`.
>   Now works fine.

Comment: You can run without edit code by append --disableHostCheck true

    ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disableHostCheck true

Comment: change the following line in node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:

if(this.disableHostCheck) return true;

change to

return true;

Comment: [See this Angular CLI GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6349) regarding disableHostCheck's potential risks, just to be aware of what you're doing.

Comment: Adetiloye's answer is much better

Comment: Run ```ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check```

Comment: modifying node_modules instead of using proper ng-cli parameters is absurdly bad practice

Answer (score 19):

In my case, I use my host name to update /etc/hosts file.

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

and add your host name last line.

```
127.0.0.1 myHostName.com
```

to connect my server,

```
ng serve -o
```

An error occurred when connecting to **myHostName.com:4200**.

so, I did like this,

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true
```

Reconnecting to **myHostName.com:4200**   :)

Comment: this is worked for me ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true. thank you @CookAtRice

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding --host 0.0.0.0 let me use my custom hostname that I have set in my Windows hosts file to switch tenants. I'm not sure why this stopped working for me, but it may have something to do with a Node.js upgrade.

Answer (score 17):

You need to run following:

```
ng serve --port 8080 --publicHost 123.34.56.78 // your server ip or host name.
```

Works for me.

Comment: ng serve --port 8080 --publicHost 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 9):

Using the command below works for me.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080  --public ipAddress
```

Comment: It works. But where can I find out the explanation about the '--public' option online? I only found out the ['--public-host' option](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve#options)

Answer (score 7):

Use the command below works for me for Angular CLI: 6.0.7

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disableHostCheck
```

Answer (score 7):

Tested on the below version of Angular and server Amazon.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.8
```

ng command options has been changed, now use `configuration` instead of `env`. The command which worked for me is

```
 ng serve --configuration=dev  --port 4009 --host 0.0.0.0 --publicHost myhost.com
```

Never use `--disable-host-check` on a public server. Angular will warn you if you use this. It may work but it is a serious security issue. You will get this message if you use that flag.

> WARNING: Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security
>   risk. See
>   https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a
>   for more information.

Please take some time to read that article it is worth reading.

Comment: this worked for me, but it was necessary to include the exact subdomain used in the browser for public-host: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host sub.myhost.com`

Answer (score 7):

> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 --public-host mydomain.com

This works for me.

Answer (score 7):

**Please, don't use the `--disable-host-check` flag for a development server!**

This is a major security issue: some malicious code can request your development server on your behalf and get the response. The problem is that the development server also sends the source code of your application, so basically, you give access to the code of the application you are building if you use that flag.

Try this instead:

```
ng serve --public-host my.dev.host.com
```

More detailed information here: [webpack-dev-server/middleware security issues](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a)

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between adding on development the `--disable-host-check` flag and using your line `ng serve --public-host my.dev.host.com` angular warns you that you are using `--disable-host-check` flag in both cases. You just need to add the conf in development

Answer (score 6):

I was facing same error after deploying my angular app on AWS EC2 instance having bitnami image. Then i launched my app with below command and it worked fine.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --disableHostCheck true
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @ruwan800's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461591/13791656), it's best to have host checking enabled at all times. This prevents attacks using [DNS Rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding).

https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a

To fix your issue, check if you have full access to your host IP. That's a likely cause.

If that doesn't solve your issue, then at your own risk, you can disable host check in your angular config. I'll advise you to do this for only your local machine though.

If you choose to do so, just set disable host check to true under your dev config in your `angular.json`.
That is, under `architect -> serve -> configurations -> development`,
set `disableHostCheck:  true`

Like:

```
"architect": {
  //...
  "serve": {
    //...
    "configurations": {
      //...
      "development": {
       //...
       "disableHostCheck": true
      }
    },
  },
  //...
}
```

This way, it only disables when running in dev mode, not when deployed on your server.

Answer (score 4):

Using the command below with the latest version of Angular CLI works for me.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host <workspace>-<username>.c9users.io
```

Answer (score 3):

This was actually solved in one of the youtube video comments thanks to **Mateusz Sawa**

Go [here](https://youtu.be/0eaWoJsanSI) to check it out.

*-- specifyng a host in package.json does not work anymore --*

just to note that it is not necessary to use the command that was used in the video, bellow instructions are enough to make the app work using regular `angular-cli` development

first you need to find the **hosts** in the **etc/** folder

type `cd ..` in the console until you reach the root of the linux machine and check always with `ls` what is listed

if you see the **hosts** file, than you are in the right location and then use `sudo vi hosts` to edit it

add the line bellow all ip addresses "0.0.0.0 *yourworkspace-yourusername.c9users.io*" (without quotes of course :-) )

also in package.json change
"start": "ng serve -H *yourworkspace-yourusername.c9users.io*"

then you just need to go to the application folder and start the app in the terminal with `npm start`

checked it just now and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I got same error. Public option solved problem for me like below:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --live-reload-port 8081 --public $C9_HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6070

use the public flag. for example: `ng serve --host <workspace>-<username>.c9users.io --public`

Answer (score 1):

Below both solutions will work. In command line :

`ng serve --public --host yourip --port yourportnumber`

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port yourport --disableHostCheck true`

Answer (score 0):

You should just change 0.0.0.0 to your local IP address like 192.168.1.42 and it should work.

```
ng serve --host 192.168.1.42
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you can only access to link you have specified in --public parameter. In my case, I have provided the IP address in --public and trying to access it with the domain I registered against that IP. But ng binds it for the only host provided in --public.

To solve this problem, I supplied one more parameter: `disable-host-check`.
Complete command: `ng serve --disable-host-check --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3100  --public  x.x.x.x`

To know more, [click here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/882)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to access our app using the `localtunnel` utility.

@tarn 's suggestion (from a comment on the accepted answer) of adding `--disableHostCheck true` to the `ng serve` command did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution if anybody still stuck in **`invalid host header`** issue:

Run `ng eject` it will create the `webpack.config.js`. 
Run `npm install` if it is asking. 
Add below `"disableHostCheck":true` to `devServer`  in `webpack.config.js`. Like below:

```
"devServer": {
    "historyApiFallback": true,
    "disableHostCheck" : true //<-- add this line
  }
```

Then in `package.json` file change `start` option under `ng` like this

`"start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port YOURPORT --public YOURIP:YOURPORT"`

Now run the angular with `npm start` command.
Thats it.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a shot

```
ng serve --host <private IP> --port <host port> --public-host <public IP>
```

Answer (score -5):

Change the line 425 in file "node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js" from false to true. i.e,

Before: return false;

Updated: return true;

Comment: Add some more description.

Comment: you should not be touching node vendors